# Is it possible to put a iPad data sim card in an iPhone 5s?

Tags: ipad, sim, iphone

I would like to purchase an iPhone 5s for data use in the US and as an international phone when overseas.  Is it possible to use an iPad SIM card in the iPhone 5s to use for data only?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what iPad you have. Here's [Apple's guide](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5554?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) to SIM cards in their devices.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will work and of course you will only have data and no phone possibilites.